# jQuery AjaxSubmit always triggers error (but still submitting)

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

I use jQueryForm plugin to submit my forms. I have it in CodeIgniter, so when I submit the form, it runs callback to check for duplicated. If there is one, it loads a view with header 401, if there isn't any - loads normal view.

I used this code for JS:

```
        function submitDeveloper() {
        $('form#addDeveloper').submit(function() {

            function getDevelopers() {
                $('li.gameDeveloper select').load(window.location + ' li.gameDeveloper select > *', function() {
                    $('.black, .addContent').fadeOut('fast');
                })
            }

            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                error: function() {
                    alert('Developer już jest w bazie!')
                },
                success: getDevelopers
            })

            return false;
        })
    }
```

Now it triggers `error` all the time, but the data is still being submitted. Funny thing is, I have other function, which is almost the same, and it works. The only difference is, I am using `beforeSubmit` there, but here I don't see any point in this.

What can this be?

Comment: It runs `alert('Developer już jest w bazie!')`, but is shouldn't.

Comment: Well, that's not the error. Try `error: function(e) {console.log(e);}` This will print the error object to the console, so you can see more clearly what's going on.

Comment: It doesn't put anything in the console (only POST, which proves that it is working), but it doesn't run `success` function either.

Comment: So looking into the plugin, it seems the documentation has some holes... Anyways, the error function seems to have this signature `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. So instead of `console.log(e)` try `console.log(arguments)`.

Comment: Still nothing. It only returns something when there really is an error (eg. when there is a duplicate in the database).